# Terraform : resource "azurerm_network_security_rule" destroy?

Tags: azure, terraform

I am trying to use terraform to manage Azure NSGs, if I use the resource **azurerm_network_security_rule** I can successfully add or update a rule... If I remove a resource azurerm_network_security_rule ... terraform tells me it's destroyed

eg .

```
 azurerm_network_security_rule.nsg-outbound-rule-300: Destroying... [id=/subscriptions/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/resourceGroups/rg-innovation-poc-002-tf/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/nsg-innovation-private-endpoint-poc-eastus2-001/securityRules/OutboundAccessToStorage]

azurerm_network_security_rule.nsg-outbound-rule-300: Destruction complete after 11s
```

If I look at the NSG in question via the AZ Cli / AZ portal... the rule still exists ? Any ideas

Comment: Could you explain "If I look at the NSG in question via the AZ Cli / AZ portal... the rule still exists"?

Comment: What I mean is that, while terraform believes it has destroyed the rule from Azure, the NSG rule is still active if I check what rules are present.

Comment: Weird, it should work as described.